# PHP Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object

Tags: php, object, phpspreadsheet

```
foreach ($data as $dt_row) {
    if ($coordinator != $dt_row->coordinator->full_name) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, "Zmiana " . $dt_row->shift_code . " - " . $dt_row->coordinator->full_name);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $dt_row->coordinator->position);
        $sheet->getStyle('A' . $row . ':B' . $row)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $coordinator = $dt_row->coordinator->full_name;
        $row++;
    }
    $sheet->setCellValue("A" . $row, $dt_row->user->full_name);
    $sheet->setCellValue("B" . $row, $dt_row->user->position);
    $row++;
}
```

returns "Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object"
data structure looks like this

```
 {
        "shift_code": "B",
        "coordinator": {
            "full_name": "name surname",
            "position": "Koordynator dzia\u0142u Kompletowania\/Monta\u017cu", ///language code here
            "shift_code": "B"
        },
        "user": {
            "full_name": "surname_emp name_emp",
            "position": "Starszy pracownik dzia\u0142u Kompletowania\/Monta\u017cu"
        }
    }
```

I think i am correctly trying to get the property but mb i cant see something

Comment: Which line triggers that error? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: is it `$dt_row->coordinator->full_name` or `$dt_row->user->full_name` that causes the error?

Comment: the first error is this "Message: Trying to get property 'coordinator' of non-object"
then every property of coordinator trigger error
i am getting data from here 
```$data = $this->bonuses_model->get_teams();```  this function return data structure from above

Comment: have you done a `var_dump($dt_row);` to see what you are dealing with?

Comment: var_dump($dt_row) returns null

Comment: Then it's pretty obivous that this error happens. Where do you set that variable?

Comment: it might prove beneficial to actually post a little more code and perhaps a more complete snippet of data

Comment: $data = $this->bonuses_model->get_teams(); 
thats how i set variable from db

Comment: Without seeing any of the other code, I'm going to assume thte value of $dt_row is incorrect because the raw data isn't being parsed correctly in the first place, so is probably returning null due to this.

Comment: the data sample above - is that directly from the db? Is there a `json_decode` call somewhere? You really should provide more details as it is hard to get a clear picture when all there is are little bits of code fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed had to add ->data  foreach ($data->data as $dt_row)  thanks for help